# how can I add a figure on the first page of presentation left side

Tags: beamer

I am trying to add a figure on the left side of a presentation first page where I have a name, instritue , date and tile. I tried to use the following but was not successful

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title{Fooing the Bar}
\author{A.~Thor}
\institute{MWE Lmt.}
\titlegraphic{\vspace{8cm}}% to push the other text to the top
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
   \tikz [remember picture,overlay]
    \node at
        ([yshift=3cm]current page.south) 
        %or: (current page.center)
        {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.5\textheight]{photo1.jpg}};
   \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I use `    \node at
        ([yshift=3cm]current page.south) 
       {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.5\textheight]{example-image-duck}};` and run your code twice I get a beautiful picture in the lower half of the title page.

Comment: what is the problem? your image is on lower part of first frame do you like to have on tleft half of frame and the title on the right side?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

it is not clear, what is your problem. your mwe works fine. it place image on bottom half of frame. however, from title of your question can be assumed, that you like to have image on the left side. please clarify your question!

below are two examples how your images can be put on the title page:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}% in real document delete option "demo"
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title{Fooing the Bar}
\author{A.~Thor}
\institute{MWE Lmt.}
%\titlegraphic{\vspace{8cm}}% to push the other text to the top
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{columns}
\column[c]{.5\linewidth}
   \tikz [remember picture,overlay]
    \node[right] at (current page.west)  
        {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight]{photo1}};
\column[c]{.5\linewidth}
    \vfil
    \titlepage
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
   \tikz [remember picture,overlay]
    \node[above] at (current page.south)   % <---
        {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.5\textheight]{photo1}};
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

as you can see, the differences between code for the second case of the title page and your *mwe* are small, for the first case is used `columns` environment.